# Easiest way to transition an overlay on hover over a photo?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm looking for css magic here. I want the user to hover over the box which already has the text on it. Then I need the black box to rise up from below and sit behind the text.

[MY JS FIDDLE HERE!](http://jsfiddle.net/thomasp423/8uqVv/1/)

I've got this:

```
<div class="box expanded">
Some text
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.expanded  {
height: 179px;
font-size: 20px;
padding-top: 130px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1000;
background-color: red;
transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.expanded:after  {
content: '';
position: absolute;
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -999;
background-color: #000;
transform: translateY(0%);
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the parent, `.box`, and set the initial position of the pseudo element to `top:100%`. On `:hover` of the pseudo element, transition it to `top:0` and add some transition properties to make it smooth.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eumBD/)

```
.box {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.expanded:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    z-index: -999;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
}
.expanded:hover:after {
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. What is the top: 100% doing exactly?

Comment: @thomasp423 It will set the position of the element to `100%` from the top. In order words, that's the height of the parent element, and this will set the element directly below it.

Answer (score -1):

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
          transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
```

Put this in .expanded class